# Thumbnail images not changing with main image in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, thumbnail

I am having issues with configurable swatch.

When click on color at product detail page main image changes but thumbnail isn't changing.

No custom extension used, Using default color swatch of magento.

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Do you find any solution for that?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/156093)